# iOS how would I implement a scroll view based overlay that can display arbitrary views at x,y coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, overlay, tiling

I'm working with a 3rd party maps vendor and would like to create an overlay for this map to display arbitrary content. I already have callout pins created, but am looking to expand that with truly any kind of content I want to put over the map.

From what I understand, this could be done by using a scroll view and tiling, but it has been a very long time since I worked with that. **Are there any projects I can take a look at to understand how to create a scroll view with tiled/reusable subviews?**

Here's how I see it working - I receive a JSON from web service, it contains a class of an item I want to display and a position. The overlay instantiates appropriate views and adds them over the map, potentially reusing and managing appearance/disappearance of components as the user scrolls the map.

Maybe there are already some mechanism built into iOS to handle overlays for arbitrary content?

Comment: I like the question, I had to implement something similar , tried to find for some 3rd party or built in , I failed and had to implement it myself ,  but if you really want to se what have I done , you can PM me by email : romalevin999@gmail.com